# How to fix "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python, typeerror

```
     12         for ii, (x, y) in enumerate(get_batches(train_x, train_y, batch_size), 1):
     13             feed = {inputs_: x,
---> 14                     labels_: y[:, None],
     15                     keep_prob: 0.5,
     16                     initial_state: state}

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: `y` is a *list*, not a numpy array, hence `y[:,None]` indeed makes no sense.

Comment: Cool. And the question is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks but this method did not solve the problem. I found the solution when the problem is done as follows.

```
        y = np.array(y)
        feed = {inputs_: x,
                labels_: y[:, None],
                keep_prob: 0.5,
                initial_state: state}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, `y` is a list. So you cannot have two values in the brackets. That is how numpy arrays work. You should probably change your code to the following:

```
feed = {inputs_: x,
        labels_: np.array(y)[:, None],
        keep_prob: 0.5,
        initial_state: state}
```

Comment: thanks but this method did not solve the problem. I found the solution when the problem is done as follows.                                                                                          
            y = np.array(y)
            
            feed = {inputs_: x,
                    labels_: y[:, None],
                    keep_prob: 0.5,
                    initial_state: state}

Comment: @YUNUSEMREKILIÇ how is this different from what I posted?

Comment: No difference, but I get the same mistake as you said. Problem solved like I did